# Where does Texmaker look for ref completion?

Tags: texmaker, editors, auto-completion

I am working on a multi-file project with texmaker and even if this options might be basic I can't find any solution yet. How to make texmaker suggest when typing `\ref{` all the labels defined in all the documents of the project and not only the one in the current document ?

I have tried to define a master document but it does not change anything.